# How should AC_CACHE_CHECK be reset?

Tags: autotools, autoconf

How should AC_CACHE_CHECK be reset?

In autoconf I am checking for headers. I've added some logic to try a little harder to find header files in std folders that might not be in the default include path. The way I do this is first attempt to find a header file with the built-in AC_CHECK_HEADER. If header is not found, I modify the CPPFLAGS and try again.

The problem with this is autoconf's caching. I want to force the check (or bypass the cache check.) If I do not force it, whether autoconf finds the header or not, it will pull what it found in the first check, ugh.

Thanks,
Chenz

Comment: None of the answers worked for you?

Answer (score 3):

Unset the cache variable, such as `ac_cv_header_syslog_h`.  You can check `config.log` for the exact spelling of the cache variable you are interested in.  Unfortunately, unsetting a shell variable cannot be done portably.  The internal workaround that Autoconf uses is using `$as_unset`, which expands to `unset` if it's supported.  So you could write:

```
$as_unset ac_cv_header_syslog_h
```

This should work in most reasonable systems nowadays, though.

A better and more straightforward solution might be to just set `CPPFLAGS` correctly for the first round of checks.  As you noticed, what you are trying isn't really supported.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I would recommend to use autoconf-style `AS_UNSET([var_name])` function. I am coding my own function on the top of `AC_CHECK_HEADERS` and the problem is that I don't know in advance the variable name(s) to unset (but I know the headers). I guess I need to reconstruct the name. What can you recommend?

Comment: @PeterEisentraut  I wonder what is the usage of the cached result of AC_CACHE_CHECK

Comment: @Bionix1441 One example: I have some checks which are more relyable if -Werror is supported by the C/C++ compilers. Unfortunately this flag will break compilation on some systems due to 3rd party headers. I abuse AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG to check whether it is safe to use this flag in order to reduce duplicated code. But caching is bad in this case as its value may change during the script execution depending on other flags or other tests.

Comment: Another use case I encountered today: you want to check a header with both the C and C++ compiler. This makes sense because not every C header works in C++ (<stdatomic.h> is an example).

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented a small macro, that does the job (at least for me). With minor changes it can be used to invalidate other cache variables:

```
# SYNOPSIS
#
# AX_RESET_HEADERS_CACHE(headers ...)
#
# DESCRIPTION
#
# This macro invalidates the headers cache variables created by previous AC_CHECK_HEADER/AC_CHECK_HEADERS checks.
#
AC_DEFUN([AX_RESET_HEADERS_CACHE], [
    AS_FOR([AX_var], [ax_var], [$1], [
        dnl You can replace "ac_cv_header_" with any prefix from http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/html_node/Cache-Variable-Index.html
        AS_VAR_PUSHDEF([ax_Var], [ac_cv_header_${ax_var}])
        AS_UNSET([ax_Var])
        AS_VAR_POPDEF([ax_Var])
    ])
]) # AX_RESET_HEADERS_CACHE
```

and usage (in this loop $1 = some library (e.g. "netpbm"), $2 = headers (e.g. "pbm.h ppm.h"), $3 = locations (e.g. "/usr/include /usr/local/include")):

```
for ac_test_location in $3 
do
    dnl Save the current state
    ax_probe_library_save_CPPFLAGS=${CPPFLAGS}

    CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -I${ac_test_location}"

    AC_MSG_CHECKING([$1 for $2 in ${ac_test_location}])
    AS_ECHO()
    _AS_ECHO_LOG([CPPFLAGS="${CPPFLAGS}"])

    AC_CHECK_HEADERS([$2], [ac_lib_$1=yes], [ac_lib_$1=no])

    dnl We have found the location, leave the loop:
    if test "${ac_lib_$1}" = "yes"
    then
        break;
    fi

    dnl Restore the state to original in case of unsuccessful attempt
    CPPFLAGS=${ax_probe_library_save_CPPFLAGS}
    AX_RESET_HEADERS_CACHE([$2])
done
```